# How to run functions with different processing rates in parallel

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I've been seeing at a lot of python async and multiprocessing tools (ray, asyncio, Process, Thread)
I'm not sure which one, if any, are the correct one for what I'm trying to do.

Basically I am live updating an animation with incoming data to my computer. The data is coming in at a rate of 10KHz(100us) and I have a function to read it. At the same time, I have a function that is running the animation at 60fps. The animation will take a snapshot of the data at the 60fps mark to update the next frame.

The issue is that some of the lines used to run the animation is 'slow' and take more than 100us to process causing the stream of the data to get scrambled when the code gets back to reading. Is there something in python that allows me to silently run and publish the readData function in the background while I let the animation function run and listen into the stream when it needs to take the data for the next frame?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Based on your description, the problem is rather CPU-bound. Thus, CPython threads does not help due to the GIL (unless the task is IO bound). Multiprocessing can be used instead, but pickling can be slow regarding the amount of data processed. If your task is compute bound, this is fine, and you should try using multiprocessing, if your task is rather memory-bound, then there is no efficient pure-Python solution (due to the cost to move data to another process). Maybe there is a trick in your specific case but this is hard to say without any practical example or more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not that knowledgeable when it comes to video, this post could be way off the mark. But it seems to me that if your data (a "frame") arrives every 1 microsecond and you want to animate at 60 frames per second, then you want to display every other 1666<sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> frames. These frame numbers (where the first frame is frame number 1) will be 16666, 333333, 50000, 66666, 83333, 100000, etc. That is, you will first skip 16665 frames to display frame 16666 as the first frame. Then you want to skip the next 16666 frames to put out frame 333333. Then you skip again the next 16666 frames to put out frame 50000. This cycle of skipping 16665 frames then 16666 frames and then 16666 frames again is repeated indefinitely. Thus on average 16665<sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> frames are being skipped before displaying the next frame. This means that one process, the "reader", is sending on average every other 16666<sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> frame (or one frame every <sup>1</sup>/<sub>60</sub><sup>th</sup> of a second) for the other process, the "animator" to receive.

This can be done as in the following simulation.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Queue
import itertools

def reader(clock, queue):
    # We are skipping on average 16665.6667 frames resulting
    # in displaying on average every other 16666.6667 frames
    # or one frame every 1/60th of a second:
    skip_counts = itertools.cycle((16665, 16666, 16666))
    skip_count = next(skip_counts)
    frame_number = 1
    frames_sent = 0

    def frame_arrived(frame):
        """This gets invoked every microsecond with a new frame"""

        nonlocal frame_number, skip_count, frames_sent

        if skip_count > 0:
            skip_count -= 1
        else:
            #print(frame_number, clock.value)
            queue.put(frame)
            frames_sent += 1
            # Reset for next frame
            skip_count = next(skip_counts)
        frame_number += 1

    # Simulate a new frame arriving every microsecond
    # Send 600 frames:
    while frames_sent < 600:
        frame_arrived(1) # For simulation, use any value
        clock.value += 1 # Advance clock 1 microsecond
    queue.put(None) # Sentinel to tell animator we are done

def animator(clock, queue):
    # Animate until we get a sentinel
    frame_count = 0
    for frame in iter(queue.get, None):
        # Animate:
        #print(frame)
        frame_count += 1
    v = clock.value # Microseconds
    seconds = v / 1_000_000
    print(f'{frame_count} frames in {seconds} seconds. The frame rate is {frame_count / seconds} fps.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock = Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    queue = Queue()

    p1 = Process(target=reader, args=(clock, queue))
    p2 = Process(target=animator, args=(clock, queue))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

Prints:

```None
600 frames in 10.0 seconds. The frame rate is 60.0 fps.
```

**Alternate Implementation**

An alternative to using a `multiprocessing.Queue` to transmit frames is to use a shared memory array (`multiprocessing.Array`) to hold a frame and a `multiprocessing.Event` instance to signal to the animator process that a new frame is available for animation. This should offer improved performance but the possibility of frames being lost exists if the animator cannot keep up with the reader of if due to contention for the CPU the animator does not get dispatched in a timely fashion.

The following code assumes a fixed size frame.

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Event, Array
import itertools

FRAME_SIZE = 10

def reader(clock, frame_arr, frame_ready, frames_animated_count):
    # We are skipping on average 16665.6667 frames resulting
    # in displaying on average every other 16666.6667 frames
    # or one frame every 1/60th of a second:
    skip_counts = itertools.cycle((16665, 16666, 16666))
    skip_count = next(skip_counts)
    frame_number = 1

    def frame_arrived(frame):
        """This gets invoked every microsecond with a new frame"""

        nonlocal frame_number, skip_count, frames_animated_count

        if skip_count > 0:
            skip_count -= 1
        else:
            #print(frame_number, clock.value)
            with frame_arr.get_lock():
                frame_arr[0:FRAME_SIZE] = frame
                frames_animated_count.value += 1
                frame_ready.set()
            # Reset for next frame
            skip_count = next(skip_counts)
        frame_number += 1

    # Simulate a new frame arriving every microsecond
    # Send 600 frames:
    while frames_animated_count.value < 600:
        frame_arrived(b'1234567890') # For simulation, use any value
        clock.value += 1 # Advance clock 1 microsecond

def animator(frame_arr, frame_ready, frames_animated_count):
    last_frames_animated_count = 0

    # This stream simulates both the video screen and an error log:
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as video:
        error_log = video
        while True:
            frame_ready.wait()
            with frame_arr.get_lock():
                frame = frame_arr[0:FRAME_SIZE]
                frame_ready.clear()
                if frames_animated_count.value != last_frames_animated_count + 1:
                    print(f'Lost frame {last_frames_animated_count + 1}', file=error_log, flush=True)
                last_frames_animated_count = frames_animated_count.value
            # Animate:
            print(last_frames_animated_count, file=video, flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    clock = Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    frames_animated_count = Value('i', 0, lock=False)
    frame_arr = Array('b', FRAME_SIZE)
    frame_ready = Event()

    Process(target=animator, args=(frame_arr, frame_ready, frames_animated_count), daemon=True).start()
    p = Process(target=reader, args=(clock, frame_arr, frame_ready, frames_animated_count))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    seconds = clock.value / 1_000_000
    print(f'{frames_animated_count.value} frames in {seconds} seconds. The frame rate is {frames_animated_count.value / seconds} fps.')
```

Prints:

```None
600 frames in 10.0 seconds. The frame rate is 60.0 fps.
```